# What are the use cases of using an async pipe and converting first to a primitive data type for interpolation?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular and I'm trying to discern what is the right approach when using interpolation for Observables-

**Option 1:**
.ts

```
intervalSync? : number;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.convertObsToPrimitive();
  }

convertObsToPrimitive(){
    interval(1000).subscribe(obs => {
      this.intervalSync = obs;
    })
  }
```

.html

```
{{ intervalSync }}
```

**Option 2:**
.ts

```
intervalAsync?: Observable<number>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.intervalAsync = interval(1000);
  }
```

.html

```
{{ intervalAsync | async }}
```

I tried both options and they have the same output, ofcourse. I'm wondering when I should use one or the other. Is there any use case that Option 1 would be applicable or am I simply bloating my code?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Maybe the output is the same, but the consequences are different as in the first case you are creating a memory leak as you never unsubscribe. In letter case you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: As normal general: always you can use pipe async, use it. It's true that you can unsubscribe in OnDestroy of your component but... why do you want to write more code?

Comment: Or version 3, `toSignal(interval(1000))`, stable in v17+, toSignal uses DestroyRef under the hood

Answer (score 1):

1. The first option won't work with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` (there are a lot of articles about `OnPush` & `Default` change-detection strategies, check it);
2. The first option requires unsubscription in `OnDestory` hook. Overwise you'll have a memory leak after component removal from the DOM. `AsyncPipe` perform unsubscription from the stream under the hood.

```
protected intervalSync? : number;
private intervalSub!: Subscription;

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.intervalSub = interval(1000).subscribe(obs => {
      this.intervalSync = obs;
    });
}

public ngOnDestory(): void {
  this.intervalSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Resume: So, yeah, in most cases when you need to render some data from the stream into a template - you should probably use `Observable` & `AsyncPipe` instead of such convertations, because it requires less management & it's more cleaner.